# Is it possible to trigger the built-in SVG presentation attribute function on regular web?

Tags: html, svg

I'm scraping one page with diagrams. There is an event listener which detects the cursor's position on the diagram and according to that generates some data and overwrites one div element. I've noticed there is a call of js function which accepts x,y cords as an argument -> transform="translate(x,y)"

```
<g class="highcharts-tooltip" zIndex="8" style="cursor:default;padding:0;white-space:nowrap;" transform="translate(394,-9999)" opacity="0">
```

I did try to edit this via element.setAttribute but finally it did not work. It changed the value visually and that's all, function did not trigger. Is there another way to do this  ?

Comment: This is unrelated to `javascript`. "translate" in this context is not a JS function. This is a value for an SVG presentation attribute. Again: it has nothing to do with JS.

Comment: @trincot while that is entirely true, the comment makes mention of the fact that a script is updating the mouse position on the page. Maybe you could show via javascript how to update that css attribute in conjuntion with the mouseover event? Maybe the `<g>` is being translated with respect to the mouse? I'd leave a thumbs up for that. If you don't want to, I don't mind taking a crack at it.

Comment: No, @trincot is correct here. `translate()` is not a JS function.  It one of several possible "transform definitions" that the `transform` attribute can have.  Read more here: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#coords-TransformAttribute